# Proguard makes my RemoteController compat implementation crash on API<19 devices

Tags: java, android, proguard, abstract-methods

I am trying to get the RemoteController API which has been introduced with API 19 to work with API 14+ since the api is already available there but hidden. I got everything to work so far, the only problem left is, that proguard seems to ruin my build on API<19 devices which results in an AbstractMethodError whenever I initialize my RemoteMetadataProvider in MicroService.java:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
        at android.media.IRemoteControlDisplay$Stub.setCurrentClientId(IRemoteControlDisplay.java)
        at android.media.IRemoteControlDisplay$Stub.onTransact(IRemoteControlDisplay.java:65)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

MicroService.java: https://github.com/tomahawk-player/tomahawk-android/blob/master/src/org/tomahawk/tomahawk_android/services/MicroService.java

My implementation is based on this guide/library by DrBreen: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2432267

The unified library by WisdomWolf I'm using: https://github.com/WisdomWolf/UnifiedRemoteMedadataProvider

My proguard config file: https://github.com/tomahawk-player/tomahawk-android/blob/master/proguard-android.txt

Everything works fine without crashing when I disable proguard completely so I'm guessing that proguard somehow strips away a needed class/interface. Any ideas on how to properly configure proguard?

My attempts so far:

- Adding "-keep class org.electricwisdom.**" and "-keep class com.woodblockwithoutco.* *" to my proguard file, since those two are the package names for the RemoteMetadataProvider library which implements the RemoteController API for API 14-18
- Adding "-keep * implements android.media.IRemoteControlDisplay" and/or "-keep * extends android.media.IRemoteControlDisplay$Stub" to my proguard file
- Adding "-keep class android.media.IRemoteControlDisplay$**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what solved my problem:
Adding "-keep class org.electricwisdom.**" and "-keep interface org.electricwisdom.* *" to my proguard config file.

Comment: If this solved your problem, then make it the answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that you are using the correct android version, files with suffix v18 are for android 4.3 and those without it for android 4.2.2 and lower.

as it is said in the very same thread that you posted

> Please do not cross-use this libraries, or you will get RuntimeException(in getInstance() method) or AbstractMethodError(if you somehow acquire instance of the RemoteMetadataProvider without calling getInstance()).

Comment: That doesn't really apply to my case because I'm using a unified version of the library. Could still be that there's a bug in the unified library ofc.